# How to configure the output of an object during json_encode?

Tags: php, json, symfony, serialization

A price object has three properties,

```
/** @var float */
public $amount = 0.0;

/** @var string */
public $currency = '';

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 */
public $dueDate;
```

When serializing this object to json via the symfony2 `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse`, it will look like:

```
{
  "price": {
    "amount": 235,
    "currency": "EUR",
    "dueDate": {
      "date": "2015-10-25 00:00:00.000000",
      "timezone": "UTC",
      "timezone_type": 3
    }
  }
}
```

I want the \DateTime to be formatted as simply a string:

```
"dueDate": "2015-10-22 00:00:00.000000"
```

How to get this done is not the scope of the question, as I currently handle this case in the object's constructor:

```
/**
 * Price constructor.
 * @param float          $amount
 * @param string         $currency
 * @param \DateTime|null $dueDate
 */
public function __construct($amount = 0.0, $currency = "", $dueDate)
{
    $this->amount = $amount;
    $this->currency = $currency;
    $this->dueDate = $dueDate;;

    if ($dueDate instanceof \DateTime) {
        $this->dueDate = $dueDate->format(\DateTime::ATOM);
    }
}
```

yet it doesn't *feel* entirely right, and I am curious if I could configure the serialize process differently, in the sense, instead of coding my representation, modify the way the object is serialized.

Reasoning is to have all `\DateTime` objects serialized that are serialized wherever in an to-be-serialized object in a same specific way, without duplicating logic. (I guess I could put the handling in an abstract class or somewhere similar, yet extending objects also has its pitfalls)

Basically:

Is there a catch an onserialize "event" where I can add some logic, or am I better off looking into [JMSSerializer](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer#introduction)?

Comment: just have your class implement the [`JsonSerializable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) class and create a method named [`jsonSerialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php) that returns an array of the data you want serialized by the [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why I didn't submit this as the answer. Since PHP 5.4.0 a [JsonSerializable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) library class is shipped with the PHP install. You can implement this class on your own and create a method named [`jsonSerialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php) that will be called whenever [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) is called with the class as the argument. A solution to your predicament could be similar to this:

```
<?php
class Price implements JsonSerializable {
    private
        $amount
    ,   $currency
    ,   $dueDate
    ;
    /**
     * Price constructor.
     * @param float          $amount
     * @param string         $currency
     * @param \DateTime|null $dueDate
     */
    public function __construct($amount = 0.0, $currency = "", $dueDate = NULL)
    {
       $this->amount = $amount;
       $this->currency = $currency;
       $this->dueDate = $dueDate;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize(){
        return array(
            'amount' => $this->amount
        ,   'currency' => $this->currency
        ,   'dueDate' => $this->dueDate instanceof \DateTime ? $this->dueDate->format(\DateTime::ATOM) : $this->dueDate
    }
}

echo json_encode(new Price(235, "EUR", new DateTime()));
```

Answer (score 1):

So you have 3 options:

- Use the JsonSerializable interface like @iam-coder proposed.
- Use a full-blown serializer like JMS (can be slow).
- Use a [transformer](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/), the plus side of this is that your output is decoupled from your data, and you can change and test each component on it's own.